# read string datastream in Flink from socket without using netcat server

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a case scenario in which I have a stream generator **client** which is generating multiple streams, merging them and sending it to socket and I want Flink program to listen to it as the **server**. As we know that server has to be turned up first, so that it can listen to client requests. I tried to do the same by using code given below

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {

    //setting the envrionment variable as StreamExecutionEnvironment
      StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        environment.setParallelism(1);


        DataStream<String> stream1 = environment.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000);
        stream1.print();



                //start the execution
     environment.execute(" Started the execution ");



}// main
```

The code for stream generator acting as client is given below

```
    DataStream<Event> stream1  = envrionment
                .addSource(new EventGenerator(2,60,1,1,100, 200 ))
                .name("stream 1")
                .setParallelism(parallelism_for_stream_rr);

    DataStream<Event> stream2  = envrionment
            .addSource(new EventGenerator(3,60,1,2,10, 20 ))
            .name("stream 2")
            .setParallelism(parallelism_for_stream_rr);


    DataStream<Event> stream3  = envrionment
            .addSource(new EventGenerator(5,60,1,3,30, 40 ))
            .name("stream 3")
            .setParallelism(parallelism_for_stream_rr);


    DataStream<Event> merged = stream1.union(stream2,stream3);

    merged.print();



            // sending data to Mobile Cep via socket

            merged.map(new MapFunction<Event, String>() {

                @Override
                public String map(Event event) throws Exception {
                    String tuple = event.toString();


                    return tuple + "\n";

                }
            }).writeToSocket("localhost", 9000, new SimpleStringSchema() );
```

Issue # 1: The issue is that client code works only when I start a Netcat server, but then Netcat server doesn't forwards the data streams.If Netcat server is not up, client code says it cant make a connection

Issue # 2: Flink program doesn't execute if Netcat server is not up

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

I know that one possible solution for this is to generate the streams within the Flink program, but I want to receive the streams via socket.

Thanks in Advance ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither Flink's socket source nor its sink starts a TCP server and waits for incoming connections. They are both clients which connect against an already started TCP server. That's also why you have to start `netcat` before launching the jobs. If you want to write to and read from a socket, then you have to write a TCP server which can buffer the incoming data and forwards them once a client connects to it.